# Guzzle without composer

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

I need to use [sproutvideo](https://github.com/SproutVideo/sproutvideo-php) php lib that requires [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Guzzle needs composer to install and not sure if is needed to run, since in some file i found

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

i never used composer and i'm on shared hosting, where i can't install it

i download Guzzle from github
but not sure i solve the autoload.php staff and if is going to work

Comment: You need to build the project in your own dev env and upload the artifact (i.e. the complete folder with all vendors, composer autoload and stuff) to shared hosting. I strongly not recommend writing your own autoloader since you will end up (in best case) with identical functionality as of composer autoloader.

Comment: did it but still not working, not sure way i got in touch with developer

Comment: "still not working" - what errors did you encounter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't go for the manual installation of Sproutvideo, because that is more of a mess than you can think of. In fact, it won't get you around using Composer for installing Guzzle at all, as you found out.

When using shared hosting (and even when using dedicated servers with root access), it is a good idea to NOT call Composer on that machine to install dependencies. You should have a way to put your regular website's files on the shared host, maybe with FTP (warning: no password encryption! Avoid it), SFTP, SCP, FTPS, WebDAV etc. Whatever it is that you use to copy your files from a local machine to the shared host, you should use it to also copy the files that Composer downloaded for you.

That means you have to run Composer on that local machine. You install it and run the command needed to download the packages you need, and to create the autoloading. After that, you can upload the files to the shared host.

Depending on how you develop, uploading and then fiddling with the files on the shared host is entirely possible, but I'd recommend preparing a local development environment. That way you won't accidentally take your live site down when you put an error in your code and instantly upload it.

In order to use the classes that are autoloaded by Composer, you simply have to include the file that resides at `vendor/autoload.php` (if your PHP file is not in the root directory, you have to use the correct path, most likely prepend `../` one or more times). After this file is included, you simply use the classes. Note that you have to use the correct namespace for the Sproutvideo library.

One more thing: The Sproutvideo library currently has no released version, so the installation instructions on the Github page are effectively wrong, because you cannot address a released version. Take this as a warning sign. Additionally, this library depends on an outdated Guzzle version 3.7. The latest version in the 3.x series is 3.9.3, and it will only be maintained until the end of the year 2015 at the latest. This is an additional warning sign. You may want to contact the maintainer of Sproutvideo and [ask to release a version](https://github.com/SproutVideo/sproutvideo-php/issues/6) and to [update the dependency on Guzzle](https://github.com/SproutVideo/sproutvideo-php/issues/7).

Answer (score 3):

You can download a packaged version of Guzzle from this site, without requiring Composer to create the dependencies.

https://php-download.com/package/guzzlehttp/guzzle

Comment: the php-download.com website is down.

Comment: Currently it tries to make you sign up and then also pay for it ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1gXi.png))

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to install Guzzle without Composer (I'm going to be setting it up on a production server, and need to keep new installs to a minimum).  Guzzle 3.x can be installed through PEAR:

https://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/getting-started/installation.html

3.x is an old version, but I'd imagine it's fine for a lot of uses.

If you're running RedHat or Centos, the EPEL repository has a package called "php-guzzle-Guzzle" which can be installed through yum.  If you do that, the way to include Guzzle in your php code is as follows:

```
<?php
require "Guzzle/autoload.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Work for me! Thanks

```
Download link: https://php-download.com/package/guzzlehttp/guzzle#all-versions
---------------------------------------------


HomeDgtInform.controller.php
---------------------------------------------
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

class HomeDgtInform extends DefaultController
{

    public static function getRootPath() {
        return realpath(__DIR__ . "/../../");
    }

    public function getInfo()
    {
        set_include_path($this->getRootPath() . '/guzzlehttp_guzzle_7.0.0.0_beta1_require/');
        require_once($this->getRootPath() ."/guzzlehttp_guzzle_7.0.0.0_beta1_require/vendor/autoload.php"); 

        try {
            $url      = 'https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com'; 
            $http     = new Client;
            $request  = new Request('GET', $url . '/facts/random?animal_type=cat&amount=2');
            $response = $http->send($request, []);

            $resp = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), false);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            $error = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }

    }


---------------------------------------------

.
├── controllers
│   └── web
│       └── HomeDgtInform.controller.php
├── guzzlehttp_guzzle_7.0.0.0_beta1_require
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── index.php
│   └── vendor
│       ├── autoload.php
```